# Replicating Row in Table if Data doesn't Exist

Tags: sql-server, insert, replicate

I currently have a sql-server database with data revolving around watt generation per second. The watt data is normally saved in second intervals, but sometimes there are inconsistencies where it is saved by a minute interval instead. Thus, instead of having 60 seconds of data saved, only one row for that minute interval is created.

When I retrieve watt data between two time points, I want it to be consistent in seconds. If there is a minute difference between two rows, is there a way to replicate the row with the data for that recorded minute 59 times (or more if the interval is larger)?

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT T1.Start_Time, T1.End_Time, T1.watts, T1.RN, T2.Start_Time, 
       T2.End_Time, T2.watts, T2.RN, DATEDIFF(second, T1.end_time, 
       T2.end_time) [span (seconds)], t2.Watts - T1.Watts [Diff], 
       (t2.Watts - T1.Watts)/1000 [Diff Kw]
FROM(select [Start_Time], [End_Time], watts, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER 
     BY watts.[Start_Time]) RN ,DATEDIFF(second, start_time, end_time) 
     span
         from dbo.watts
         where watts.SubMeter_Id = 21 
         AND watts.End_Time >= dateadd(S, 1538701191, '1970-01-01') 
         AND watts.End_Time <= dateadd(S, 1538787591, '1970-01-01')
         AND DATEDIFF(second, watts.start_time, watts.end_time)>=1
      ) AS T1

LEFT JOIN (select [Start_Time], [End_Time], watts, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (ORDER BY watts.[Start_Time]) RN ,DATEDIFF(second, 
            start_time, end_time) span
                 from dbo.watts
                 where watts.SubMeter_Id = 21 
                 AND watts.End_Time >= dateadd(S, 1538701191, '1970-01-01') 
                 AND watts.End_Time <= dateadd(S, 1538787591, '1970-01-01')
                 AND DATEDIFF(second, watts.start_time, watts.end_time)>=1
          ) AS T2
ON T1.RN = T2.RN-1
```

Sample data in Watts table:

```
ID  |  Submeter_Id  |  Watts  |  Start_Time  |  End_Time     
3705255 | 19 | 16428779218 | 2018-09-27 07:28:26.000 | 2018-09-27 07:28:27.000
3705256 | 19 | 16428784527 | 2018-09-27 07:28:58.000 | 2018-09-27 07:28:59.000
```

Sample current output:

```
Start_Time | End_Time | watts | RN | Start_Time | End_Time | watts | RN | span (seconds) | Diff | Diff Kw
2018-10-05 01:39:23.000 | 2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 | 2858527031558 | 2362 | 2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 | 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 | 2858527122527 | 2363 | 1 | 90969 | 90
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 | 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 | 2858536311254 | 2364 | 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 | 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 | 2858542101255 | 2365 | 60 | 5790001 | 5790
```

Currently, this query outputs all the rows between the two given timestamps. The time span column is usually 1 second, but sometimes the data is saved per minute instead. I can't figure out how to get the rows to be replicated if the time difference between two columns is greater than 1 second.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share with us some sample data, a few rows of 1 second, and some of 1 minute.  Does the 1 minute row have 60 in the watts column? Would replicating the row and changing only the start_time and end_time to 1 second ALSO require that the watts column also be changed?  Please also share sample output .

Comment: I've added sample data from the table the query is being executed on, and the sample output of the current query. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You didn't answer the question of @donPablo. If you add 59 records, how to distribute the Watt deltas over the seconds?

Comment: I apologize for not answering the question earlier, yes ideally the watts would be changed, that is divided by the amount of records being replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has only a few columns of the repeated rows that have been adjusted.  Specifically watts(only on T1), Diff, and [Diff Kw].

I realize that it may be desirable to also have T1.Start_Time, T1.End_Time adjusted by 1 second, and also the T2 times adjusted, and t2.watts.  Which I leave for your exercise.  Results are also given below.

```
;With cteMatched as (
    SELECT 
        T1.Start_Time, T1.End_Time, T1.watts, T1.RN, 
        T2.Start_Time ST2, T2.End_Time ET2, T2.watts W2, T2.RN RN2, 
        DATEDIFF(second, T1.end_time, T2.end_time) [span (seconds)], 
        t2.Watts - T1.Watts [Diff], 
        (t2.Watts - T1.Watts)/1000 [Diff Kw]
    FROM(SELECT T1a.[start_time],
                T1a.[end_time],
                T1a.watts,
                Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY T1a.[start_time]) As  RN,
                Datediff(second, T1a.start_time, T1a.end_time) span
         FROM   dbo.watts As T1a
         WHERE  T1a.submeter_id = 21
                AND T1a.end_time >= Dateadd(s, 1538701191, '1970-01-01')
                AND T1a.end_time <= Dateadd(s, 1538787591, '1970-01-01')
                AND Datediff(second, T1a.start_time, T1a.end_time) >= 1
         ) AS T1

    LEFT JOIN ((SELECT T2a.[start_time],
                T2a.[end_time],
                T2a.watts,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY T2a.[start_time])       RN,
                Datediff(second, T2a.start_time, T2a.end_time) span
         FROM   dbo.watts As T2a
         WHERE  T2a.submeter_id = 21
                AND T2a.end_time >= Dateadd(s, 1538701191, '1970-01-01')
                AND T2a.end_time <= Dateadd(s, 1538787591, '1970-01-01')
                AND Datediff(second, T2a.start_time, T2a.end_time) >= 1
         )) AS T2
    ON T1.RN = T2.RN-1 
    Where T2.RN > 0
)

Select  * From cteMatched Where [span (seconds)] = 1
union all


SELECT 
Start_Time, End_Time,   
cast(watts + ((Diff / [span (seconds)]) * rnxx) as numeric(18,0)) , RN, 
ST2,    ET2,    W2, RN2,    1,  
cast((Diff / [span (seconds)]) as numeric(18,0)),   
cast(([Diff Kw] / [span (seconds)]) as numeric(18,2))
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX([span (seconds)])+1 FROM cteMatched) rnxx = ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
          FROM sys.all_columns 
          ORDER BY [object_id]
    ) as x

CROSS JOIN cteMatched AS d

WHERE x.rnxx <= d.[span (seconds)] 
AND [span (seconds)] <> 1
ORDER BY (1);  

Start_Time  End_Time    watts   RN  ST2 ET2 W2  RN2 span (seconds)  Diff    Diff Kw
2018-10-05 01:39:23.000 2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2858527031558   1   2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527122527   2   1   90969   90.969000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527219250   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527315974   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527412697   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527509421   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527606144   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527702868   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527799591   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527896315   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858527993038   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528089761   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528186485   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528283208   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528379932   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528476655   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528573379   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528670102   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528766826   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528863549   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858528960272   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529056996   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529153719   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529250443   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529347166   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529443890   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529540613   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529637336   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529734060   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529830783   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858529927507   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530024230   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530120954   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530217677   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530314401   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530411124   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530507847   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530604571   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530701294   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530798018   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530894741   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858530991465   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531088188   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531184912   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531281635   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531378358   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531475082   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531571805   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531668529   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531765252   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531861976   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858531958699   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532055423   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532152146   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532248869   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532345593   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532442316   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532539040   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532635763   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532732487   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532829210   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858532925934   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533022657   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533119380   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533216104   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533312827   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533409551   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533506274   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533602998   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533699721   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533796445   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533893168   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858533989891   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534086615   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534183338   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534280062   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534376785   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534473509   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534570232   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534666955   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534763679   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534860402   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858534957126   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535053849   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535150573   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535247296   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535344020   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535440743   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535537466   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535634190   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535730913   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535827637   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858535924360   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858536021084   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858536117807   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858536214531   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:39:24.000 2018-10-05 01:39:25.000 2858536311254   2   2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536311254   3   1   96723   96.720000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536407754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536504254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536600754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536697254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536793754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536890254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858536986754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537083254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537179754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537276254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537372754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537469254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537565754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537662254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537758754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537855254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858537951754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538048254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538144754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538241254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538337754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538434254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538530754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538627254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538723754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538820254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858538916754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539013254   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539109754   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539206255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539302755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539399255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539495755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539592255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539688755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539785255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539881755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858539978255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540074755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540171255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540267755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540364255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540460755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540557255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540653755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540750255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540846755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858540943255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541039755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541136255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541232755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541329255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541425755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541522255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541618755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541715255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541811755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858541908255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858542004755   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
2018-10-05 01:40:00.000 2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2858542101255   3   2018-10-05 01:41:00.000 2018-10-05 01:42:00.000 2858542101255   4   1   96500   96.500000
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you so much for your help!